# Is an RT license required for EASA PPL holders?

Tags: radio-communications, easa-regulations, ppl

Is an RT (radiotelephony) license required in the EU for an EASA PPL holder acting as PIC in an EU-based aircraft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EASA itself does not require a RT license (RT is usually legislated on national level), however, it gives the state issuing your license the possibility to include RT privileges as part of your license (item XIII in the license).

This is also the most common case, ie, your PPL will most likely include RT privileges, so you will not need an RT license in addition to this.

What EASA state are you planning to have your PPL issued in?

Comment: unless things changed, the Netherlands definitely requires a separate RT license. Then again, anything to make a quick Euro, they used to require one even for cellphones in the pre-GSM days...

Comment: I am still confused with it: there is separate "communication" topic in theory course and exams, we pass ICAO English as international aviation language, but, as I understand, almost all EU countries still require that license, and most of them require separate exam (for example, RTOL in England or RT in Czech) in its own language...

Comment: During your training, you will need a student license. Typically, the student license does not include radio privileges, thus the need for a separate radio license (which then typically becomes "embedded" into your PPL).

Comment: @Waked I believe radio "privileges" don't come with PPL (at least in most of the EU countries, I know 7 where it is needed for sure). Can you specify where not? Usually a separate license is required. And in some countries an ICAO language exam is needed to fly abroad

Comment: @GabrielVince Could you please list states where it is required if you already have filled "RT privileges" section in the PPL? I know only about UK and NL.

Comment: Sure SK, CZ, NL and BE. You will need a separate radio license. I really doubt there is RT mentioned in PPL though format of these documents has changed last years. I could do the exam in BE in English with no problems

Comment: @GabrielVince I don't disprove of what you are saying, but please provide references to to current regulations. As indicated by my answer, national legislation on radio DO exist and may differ between countries. The only EASA requirement is is FCL.055 (requirement for language proficiency endorsment). (Sidenote: The PPL skill test content [AMC FCL.235] includes R/T procedures). (Another interesting sidenote: Airline pilots may overfly 20 different european countries in a single day, each country with individual national legislation).

Comment: @Waked: this is an example of the regulation: http://www.laa.sk/obmedzene-osvedcenie-radiotelefonistu-leteckej-pohyblilvej-sluzby-ii/ FCL.055 only claims the pilot must prove sufficient level of English to use the radio (it doesn't automatically grant any right to do so). And indeed, you can fly over multiple coutries where all have "harmonized" legislation and mutually acknowledge all official documents (PPL, medical certificate, radio license). Let's try to fly outside EU and you will have to check internation agereements or local legislation. It is similar to the driving liecenses

Comment: @avtomaton why you insist so heavily on having RT granted by PPL? Did you get forbidden to use radio? If you can do PPL, the RT license will be piece of cake

Comment: @GabrielVince I do not insist, I am just curious. I also do not see anything wrong or difficult in that exam, but I just asked whether CAA in some EU countries approves RT privileges granted by RT section of PPL (if it exists there, of course: I do not know exact PPL forms in all EU countries), and what do pilots recently passed exams in any state have in their PPLs. Your link to SK website seems related to gliders, hang-gliders and ultralights (that kind of license definitely does not have RT-related section and the pilot definitely should have separate license to operate on-board radio).

Comment: To be consistent between posts, this is answer from another chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37321336#37321336 in CZ you need VFL or OFL license (as described https://www.ctu.cz/druhy-prukazu)